# Angular 6 create dynamic css Class

Tags: angular, angular6

[image]

I have Issue to create Dynamic css class in component HTML file... Right now I am using inline css like this

```
<div class="" [style.color]="mapData.theme.bodyFontColor"></div>
```

using angular functionalty.. but i need a class where I should change attribute dynamically. 
Example

```
.wrapper{
 color : mapData.theme.bodyFontColor;
 font-family: mapData.theme.bodyFontFamily;
}
```

if you seen screenshot there is a option to change color of template so just I need to update that color instantly in my class attribute..

is it possible?

Comment: You can't assign a `ts value` to a css/scss definition, but you can use `[ngStyle]` to dinamically change the css value binded to a variable defined in the ts code. IE: `<div class="wrapper" [ngStyle]="{'color' : mapData.theme.bodyFontColor}"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: you can do it by using global css-class. E.g. in Angular-CLI we can define global classes in `./src/styles.scss` and there you can define your class with default values e.g.

```
.wrapper {
 color : black;
}
```

And then inside you component `.ts` you can dynamically modify this class using direct access to document styles as follows (for standard angular-CLI `styles.scss` is at index 2 - `.styleSheets[2]` but it can change in different versions/projects - it also depends of previously defined additional styles in `index.html` file)

```
let wrapperClass = [...(<any>document.styleSheets[2]).cssRules]
                    .find(x=> x.selectorText=='.wrapper');

wrapperClass.style.color = mapData.theme.bodyFontColor;
wrapperClass.style['font-family'] = mapData.theme.bodyFontFamily
```

In this way you can also access to pseudo elements e.g. `.wrapper:hover`. You can use this approach (direct access to document styles) to load (e.g. from database) dynamic skin for whole frontend (in that case you should not use local-styles for your components but only global in ./src/style.scss)

Answer (score -2):

Yes this is possible,

```
<div [className]="'class' + someValue"></div
```

you can use class attribute for this. Check **[here](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-ngclass)** for more info.

Comment: its not a solution.. please check my question... I want to change class attribute dynamically..

.wrapper{
 color: changecolor
}

changecolor will be change from ts or from input..

Comment: I see. How about using ngclass and class function inaide it ?  <button [ngClass]="calculateClasses()" 
                        (click)="submit()">Button</button> Inside calculateclass you can change the class value and return updated class